# Text inside canvas Square doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to generate green squares on canvas and then put a white *"X"* inside all of them. The problem is that when i use my `writeX()` function with coordinates inside the square the text doesn't appear. How can I solve this?

```
function drawSquare(xR,yR) {   
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle='rgba(124,252,0,0.5)';
    ctx.fillRect(xR,yR,60,60);
    ctx.strokeRect(xR,yR,60,60)
    ctx.closePath();
}

function writeX(xR,yR) {
    ctx.font = "30px Impact";
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText("X", xR+30,yR+40);
}

function generateSquares() {
    for(i=0;i<currentSquares;i++) {
        var coords=new Array;
        coords=String(positions[i]).split(';',5);
        drawSquare(coords[0],coords[1]);
        writeX(coords[0],coords[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `positions` variable is an `Array`:

```
var positions = ['0;0', '61;0', '121;0', '0;61', '61;61', '121;61']
```

And `currentSquares` is a number which reflects the amount of possible positions:

```
var currentSquares = positions.length
```

This runs:

```js
var positions = ['0;0', '61;0', '121;0', '0;61', '61;61', '121;61']; // pairs of 'X;Y'
var currentSquares = positions.length;

var canvas = document.querySelector('#surface');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function toNumber (x) {
  return Number(x);
}

function drawSquare(xR,yR) {   
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle='rgba(124,252,0,0.5)';
    ctx.fillRect(xR,yR,60,60);
    ctx.strokeRect(xR,yR,60,60)
    ctx.closePath();
}

function writeX(xR,yR) {
    ctx.font = "30px Arial"; // changed "Impact" to "Arial" because "Impact" isn't necessarily installed for every user
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.fillText("X", xR+30,yR+40);
}

function generateSquares() {
    for(var i=0; i < currentSquares; i++) {
        var coords = positions[i].split(';').map(toNumber); // need to cast "positions" pair into Numbers
        drawSquare(coords[0], coords[1]);
        writeX(coords[0], coords[1]);
    }
}

generateSquares();
```

```html
<canvas id="surface" width="182" height="182"></canvas>
```